# How to send TCPDUMP output to remote script via CURL

Tags: bash, tcpdump

So I have a script here that is taking a TCPDUMP output. We are trying to send (2) variables to a PHP script over the web ($SERVER). The filename header is created and contains both $FILETOSEND which is the filename and filedata. The actual data for the filedata variable is coming from a file called 1 (the data is formatted as you can tell). I am having issues with the section that calls out #send common 10 sec dump.

I am trying to CURL the file 1 and I am doing so by using curl --data "$(cat 1)" $SERVER

The script isn't sending the file 1 at all, mostly just sends the filename and no file data. Is there a problem with the way I am sending the file? Is there a better way to format it?

```
while true; do                                                                
sleep $DATASENDFREQ;
killall -9 tcpdump &> /dev/null
if [ -e $DUMP ]; then                                                     
    mv $DUMP $DUMP_READY
fi                             
create_dump                             

DATE=`date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"`
FILETOSEND=$MAC-$DATE-$VERSION          
# we write fileheader to the file. 2 vars : filename, filedata.
FILEHEADER="filename=$FILETOSEND&filedata="
    echo $FILEHEADER > 2       
# change all colons to underscores for avoiding Windows filenames issues
    sed -i 's/:/_/g' 2                     
# delete all newlines \n in the file
    tr -d '\n' < 2 > 1                                                  
# parsing $DUMP_READY to awk.txt (no header in awk.txt)        
awk '{ if (NF > 18 && $10 == "signal") {print "{\"mac\": \""$16"\",\"sig\": \""$9"\",\"ver\": \""$8"\",\"ts\": \""$1"\",\"ssid\": \""$19"\"}" }}' $DUMP_READY > awk.txt 
sed -i 's/SA://g' awk.txt     
sed -i 's/&/%26/g' awk.txt                                              

cat awk.txt >> 1                    
sync                                                                    

    # send $OFFLINE                                                                                                            
    if [ -e $OFFLINE ]; then    
            curl -d $OFFLINE $SERVER                                    
            if [ $? -eq "0" ]; then                                                                                            
                    echo "status:dump sent;msg:offline dump sent"
                    rm $OFFLINE     
            else                                                        
                    echo "status:dump not sent;msg:offline dump not sent"                                                      
            fi                      
    fi                                                                  

# send common 10 secs dump                                                                                                     
curl --data "$(cat 1)" $SERVER                                          
if [ $? -eq "0" ]; then                                
    echo "status:dump sent"                                                                                                    
else                           
    cat 1 >> $OFFLINE                                  
    echo "status:dump not sent"                                                                                                
fi                                                               

if [ -e $DUMP_READY ]; then         
    rm -f $DUMP_READY 1 2 upload_file*                                   
fi
```

Comment: You're missing part of the `awk` command, all the rest of the code highlighting is messed up.

Comment: Quote the variable: `curl -d "$OFFLINE"`. Also, don't use uppercase variable names, those are for environment variables and built-in variables.

Comment: Where do you set `$OFFLINE`?

Comment: To send the contents of a file, you need to use `@filename`.